# Nested loops does not work correctly for xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, umbraco

I have been using a CMS which is called Umbraco(umbraco.org) and for displaying flash news on the website using SlideShowPro Standalone product(www.slideshowpro.net)

In brief I created a section on admin panel as follows.

-Flash(which has a xslt file)
    - Month name
         - A node with image
         - A node with video

Every month I will be creating a node with name of the month and add image and videos to them. Month node might have all image or video perhaps both are mixed.
I do not have any input xml file cause on SlideShowPro Standalone has only a file which outputs desired xml file for flash

here is the xml file:

```
<album id="ssp" lgPath="" tnPath="" title="Album One" description="" tn="">
    <img src="1.jpg" id="id1" title="" caption="" link="" target="_blank" pause="" />
    <img src="1.f4v" id="id1" tn="" title="" caption="" link="" target="_blank" pause="" vidpreview" />
</album>
```

What I did in xslt file is;

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/node [string(data [@alias='umbracoNaviHide']) != '1']">
            <album lgPath="http://localhost" tnPath="http://localhost" title="{data[@alias = 'albumTitle']}" description="{data[@alias = 'albumDescription']}" tn="http://localhost">
                <xsl:for-each select="node">
                    <xsl:if test = "string-length(./data [@alias = 'image']) &gt; 0" >                                                  
                                                <img src="{data[@alias = 'image']}" title="{data[@alias = 'title']}" caption="{data[@alias = 'caption']}" link="{data[@alias = 'link']}" target="_blank" pause=""/>                                                         
                    </xsl:if>       
                    <xsl:if test = "string-length(./data [@alias = 'video']) &gt; 0" >                                                  
                                                <img src="{data[@alias = 'video']}" tn="http://localhost" title="{data[@alias = 'title']}" caption="{data[@alias = 'caption']}" link="{data[@alias = 'link']}" target="_blank" pause="" vidpreview="/flash/gallery/album2/video/1_preview.png"/>                                                        
                    </xsl:if>

                </xsl:for-each>     
                        </album>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

and that outputs

```
<album lgPath="http://localhost" tnPath="http://localhost" title="" description="" tn="http://localhost"><img src="/media/951/untitled.png" title="örnek" caption="örnek" link="" target="_blank" pause=""/><img src="/media/1026/1.f4v" title="flash" caption="flash" link="" target="_blank" pause=""/></album>
```

Even though Larsh pointed out that I should use  statament, the result is same...

Comment: @deniz_seaside: See my answer for some hints. They are only hints, because you haven't provided any source XML. This is as when calling a plumber and not letting him into the house. Bad! I have voted to CLOSE this question as INCOMPLETE.

Comment: @Deniz: the first XML excerpt you showed, "here is the xml file", is clearly the *output* XML. The last XML excerpt you showed is also output. We need to see the **input**.

Comment: @Dimitre: About the `node` element, I think this is the result of some extension function in Umbraco. @deniz-seaside: What is the question? For what I can see the only difference between image and video are @tn and @vidpreview (@scr could be just `data[@alias='video' or @alias='image']`). So, you could wrap this attributes only with some `xsl:if`. Also your `fn:string-length` test is not good. You could test for existence instead.

Comment: @Alejandro, good point about the string-length test. I too was going to say he should test for existence, but then I thought, maybe he has empty data elements and they don't count (he needs the content for his src attribute), so maybe he really means `string-length(...) > 0`. Hard to tell without input data. So it's worth asking. @deniz, if you don't actually have empty data elements with alias='image', use `data[@alias = 'image']` instead of `string-length(./data [@alias = 'image']) &gt; 0`.

Comment: So what is your question? I don't see one. It seems that when you apply the fragment of a transformation (you haven't shown the whole transformation!!!) on the XML document which you don't have any idea about, that the result (or part of!) that you get is not what you expect (not shown again!!!). And it seems to me that your question (that you didn't ask at all) could be: what you are doing wrong? If this is so, the answer is: everything. One shouldn't waste even a single second to write a transformation that processes an unknown XML document.

Comment: @deniz_seaside: I have updated my answer. Please use one of the two transformations in the update and you'll get the source XML document. Then, please edit your question and provide, `finally`, this XML document.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what your source data is like, but assuming that it doesn't have nested <node> elements, the problem is that the second xsl:for-each should be

```
<xsl:for-each select=".">
```

because the context item inside the first for-each will be the <node> element, therefore the instruction you posted would be seeking a further child element.

Comment: OK. It looks like this isn't the issue, could you post some sample source data.

Comment: by meaning source data you mean whole xslt file?

Comment: No, I mean that input xml file which you are applying the xslt to.

Comment: Sorry, I can't seen the input xml in your comment - can you post it in a code block in the question

Comment: I really need to be able to see the input to be able to be able to work out what is going wrong. Can you replace your stylesheet with an <xsl:copy-of select="."/> which should hopefully should copy your input to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Nasılsınız?!

Deniz, it would still be good to see your input XML. It looks like what you posted in your comment was a bit of the desired output XML. The best way to post it is to edit your original question and put the input XML there, at least a sample.

In the meantime, I'm wondering, is it possible for a `<node>` element to have both a

```
<data alias="image">
```

child **and** a

```
<data alias="video">
```

child? If so, that would explain why in those cases you're not getting the `<img src="{data[@alias = 'video']}">` output.

The `<xsl:choose>` instruction will only "execute" one of the `<xsl:when>` instructions each time the `<xsl:choose>` is processed (in this case, once for every iteration of the `<xsl:for-each>` loop). So if there is a `data[@aliasIf you need to be able to handle both an image data child and a video data child, use

```
<xsl:if test=...>
```

for each of them, instead of

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test=...>
```

If that doesn't address the problem, please do post a sample of your input XML, and format it using the 'code' formatting button (with the `101 010` icon).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: @deniz_seaside, please give us the XML document and also see it for the first time.

Then, probably, you'll write your transformation again, this time much better.

**Here is how to obtain the XML document that you don't have**: just apply this transformation to this unknown document:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Or even shorter**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/node [string(data [@alias='umbracoNaviHide']) != '1']"> 
            <album lgPath="http://localhost" tnPath="http://localhost" title="{data[@alias = 'albumTitle']}" description="{data[@alias = 'albumDescription']}" tn="http://localhost"> 
                <xsl:for-each select="node">
```

The second `<xsl:for-each>` is most likely incorrect. It will select for processing all nodes named `node` of the current node, which is also named `node`. Usually a node named `node` doesn't have children named `node`, too.

The solution is to remove the second `<xsl:for-each>` instruction and leave its content ( body) in the body of the first `<xsl:for-each>` instruction.

**Do note**:

1. **As you haven't provided any source XML document, your problem is most likely duew to the bad weather**.
2. **Never use the name `node`** for an element, attribute or processing-instruction. You are increasing the chances of getting confused and committing errors by a factor of 1000.

Comment: Dimitre thanks for the valuable infos. I supplied all the infos I could find but I would take into consedaration your suggestion as well. I am also not good at xslt and try to gain knowledge for it.